# Android FragmentManager and Fragment Result API

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment

How can be that a fragment F which uses the new Fragment Result API to get results from 2 other fragments: A, B gets the result from A but not from B because B has a different parent FragmentManager (and I don't know why) ? How could be something like that ? 2 fragments called in the same way but they end up having same Activity but different FragmentManager ? The function calls are the following:

//THIS DOESN'T WORK. THE LISTENER IS NOT CALLED AFTER THE RESULT IS SET

```
private fun navigateToItemLocation() {

        setFragmentResultListener(REQUEST_LOCATION_KEY) { s: String, bundle: Bundle ->

            val locationId = bundle.getParcelable<ParcelUuid>(LOCATION_ID)!!.uuid
            viewModel.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val location = LocationRepository().get(locationId)!!
                changeItemLocation(location)
            }
        }


        val action = ItemRegistrationPagerHolderDirections.actionNavItemRegistrationPagerToNavStockLocationSelection()
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

//THIS WORKS FINE:

```
private fun navigateToItemDetails(item: Item2) {

        setFragmentResultListener(SELECTED_ITEM_KEY) { s: String, bundle: Bundle ->

            val propertySetId = bundle.getParcelable<ParcelUuid>(SELECTED_ITEM_SET_ID)!!.uuid
            clearFragmentResultListener(SELECTED_ITEM_KEY)

            viewModel.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val repository = PropertySetRepository()
                val propertySet = repository.get(propertySetId)!!
                val propertySetInfo = ItemFactory.loadPropertySetInfo(propertySet)

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { setPackageCode(null) }
                selectItem(item.item, propertySetInfo, item.description, null)
            }
        }

        val action = ItemRegistrationPagerHolderDirections.actionNavItemRegistrationToNavStockItemDetails(ParcelUuid(item.item.id), true)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

Both fragments A and B are in a separate Dynamic Feature. The only single problem I have is that when the following function is called:

```
fun onSelect() {

        viewModel.pickedLocation.value = (viewModel.selectedLocation as? LocationExt2?)?.location
        val result = bundleOf(Pair(LOCATION_ID, ParcelUuid(viewModel.pickedLocation.value!!.id)))
        setFragmentResult(REQUEST_LOCATION_KEY, result)
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }
```

> setFragmentResult(REQUEST_LOCATION_KEY, result)

Doesn't produce any result because the FragmentManager is not the same of the calling Fragment. The same method in fragment A which is:

```
private fun onSetSelected(id: UUID) {

    propertySets.removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)
    adapter.tracker = null
    setFragmentResult(SELECTED_ITEM_KEY, bundleOf(Pair(SELECTED_ITEM_SET_ID, ParcelUuid(id))))
    findNavController().popBackStack()
}
```

As a temporarily workaround I replaced the call to Fragment's FragmentManager with Activity.supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener. It works but still I do not understand why fragments A and B behave differently...

Answer (score 4):

Check that fragment where you listen for fragment result and fragment where you set the result are in the **same** fragment manager.

Common case where this would happen is if you are using `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()` or `Fragment.getParentFragmentManager()` alongside `Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: How to check if they are in same fragment manager? what API I should call?

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog article for the principles and rules with Fragment Result API on medium: https://medium.com/@FrederickKlyk/state-of-the-art-communication-between-fragments-and-their-activity-daa1fe4e014d

> Only one listener can be registered for a specific request key.

> If more than one listener is registered on the same key, the previous one will be replaced by the newest listener.